# How to use IndicatorView in CarouselPage?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to add an Indicator View style dots to my CarouselPage; However, the documentation I have found only shows how to use the new IndicatorView with CarouselView.

Is there anyway to use it with CarouselPage instead? If not, Is there anything similar to IndictorView that's used for CarouselPage? Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CarouselPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="Page.MainPage">
    <ContentPage>
        <StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,0">
                <Image Source="LOGO.png"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HeightRequest="195"
                       WidthRequest="205"
                       />
                <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                      <Image Source="bg.png"
                             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.35, 0.6, -1, 1" 
                             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"          
                             HeightRequest="330"
                             WidthRequest="200"/>
                      <Image Source="Device.png"
                             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.45, 0.4, -1, -1" 
                             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  
                             HeightRequest="252"
                             WidthRequest="290"/>
                </AbsoluteLayout>     
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Welcome"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       TextColor="White"
                       Padding="0,15"
                       Font="Bold,20"/>

                    <Label Text="This is page 1"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Padding="25,0"
                       TextColor="White"/>
                </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage BackgroundColor="#3e454d">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#3e454d">     
                <AbsoluteLayout>
                      <Image Source="Map.png"
                             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.4, 0.7, -1, -1" 
                             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"          
                             HeightRequest="330"
                             WidthRequest="205"/>
                      <Image Source="Device.png"
                             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.45, 0.7, -1, -1" 
                             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  
                             HeightRequest="282"
                             WidthRequest="340"/>
                </AbsoluteLayout>     
                <StackLayout Padding="10,10">
                    <Label Text="Join US"
                       TextColor="White"
                       Padding="0,0,0,15"
                       Font="Bold,22"/>

                    <Label Text="This is Page 2"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="18"
                       TextColor="White"/>
                </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</CarouselPage>
```

Comment: CarouselPage has been deprecated in favor of CarouselView

Comment: @sisi did you solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CarouselView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/) instead of `CarouselPage` , embedd `CarouselPage.Content` to `CarouselView.ItemLayout` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/populate-data)

Note that `IndicatorView` is different view, its not embedded in CarouselPage , even in CarouselView , you have to give the binding reference to CarouselView in order for it to work.

Also note that IndicatorView is still in [Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/indicatorview) mode you need to set the experimental flag in order to make it work

```cs
 Forms.SetFlags("IndicatorView_Experimental");
```

Also its showing [Carouselview is in preview too(It was not, weird!)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/introduction)

so you may have to set experimental flag for that as well

```cs
Forms.SetFlags("CarouselView_Experimental");
```